# playstore upload version change after upload apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-manifest

I have created an Android app in the ionic framework and now I am trying to upload it to the Android Playstore.

When I upload my app to the Playstore it shows as version 18 but my AndroidManfest.xml file has the following version in it:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1"  ........>
```

And this comes from config.xml of the root directory of my ionic project.

My Config.xml is:

```
<widget id="com.xxx.xxx" version="0.0.1">
```

I don't know where Android Playstore gets version as 18(0.0.1).

How can I change the version number in the Playstore to 1(0.0.1)?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the version to `0.0.18` to get version code as 18.

ex:

```
<widget id="com.ionicframework.test" version="0.0.18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>
```

here
 `AndroidManifest.xml` will be updated to 2 in `android:versionCode=”18”` upon project built

**OR**

you can add extra parameter in your widget called versionCode, that will define the corresponding app version code

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    version     = "0.0.1"
    versionCode = "18">
```

[Reference_2](http://learn-daily.com/change-and-update-version-code-in-ionic-framework/)

[Reference_2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/versioncode-not-updating-on-android-apk/7305)

Comment: i don't want 18. i need 1 but playstore shows as 18. i don't know how can i change 18 to 1..

Comment: Yes i already tried that i added android-versionCode="1" in config.xml